# Share file failed because the file names are too long

Tags: ios, xamarin

I used below codes to pop up system share feature.

```
    public void Share(List<String> filepath)
    {
        NSObject[] activityItems = new NSObject[filepath.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in filepath)
        {
            activityItems[i] = NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(item, false, null);
            i++;
        }

        var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
        {
            // Phone
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController != null)
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(
                    activityController, true, null);
        }
        else
        {
            // Tablet
            var popup = new UIPopoverController(activityController);
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController != null)
            {
                UIView view = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
                CGRect rect = new CGRect(view.Frame.Width / 2, view.Frame.Height, 50, 50);
                popup.PresentFromRect(rect, view, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Test results:

- sharing via `Mail` App, the result is OK.
- sharing via `AirDrop`, the file name length is normal, OK.
- sharing via `AirDrop`, the file name length is long, FAILED.

For some reason, I can not decrease the file name length, so how to solve the problem?

Comment: what constitutes "long" vs "normal"?

Comment: The maximum length is 20

Comment: There seems a limitation of the length of file name. You can have a try yo shorten the directory names.